# ConstrainToParentBounds from C# instead of XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

To constrain a draggable object in XAML to its parent container I can do the following.

```
<Image Name="myImage" Source="Images/MyImage.png">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <el:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Image>
```

How would I do this in C#? My best guess which appears to be incorrect was:

```
myImage.SetValue(MouseDragElementBehavior.ConstrainToParentBoundsProperty, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the behaviors from code. You can change to property on the returned object.

```
System.Windows.Interactivity.Interaction.GetBehaviors(myImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Andras stated, I needed to get the behavior collection. However, I also needed to add a new event since the MouseDrageElementBehavior was not already in the behavior collection.

```
BehaviorCollection behaviors = Interaction.GetBehaviors(myImage);
var mouseDragBehavior = new MouseDragElementBehavior();
mouseDragBehavior.ConstrainToParentBounds = true;
behaviors.Add(mouseDragBehavior);
```